# Joining two tables in mysql with an external mapping between columns of two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I want to join two tables in a database.  My first table looks like

```
deviceId                   rssi date        timestamp   f   po  pps         counter b   Id  f
fd00::212:4b00:1957:ce2f    60  10-12-2019  00:00:08    0   100 26.36000061 3348    B2W 39  L1
fd00::212:4b00:1957:ce2f    60  10-12-2019  00:00:18    0   100 25.62000084 3349    B2W 41  L1
fd00::212:4b00:1957:ce2f    60  10-12-2019  00:00:28    0   0   24.29999924 3350    B2W 46  L1
fd00::212:4b00:1957:ce2f    60  10-12-2019  00:00:38    0   100 24.48999977 3351    B2W 48  L1
```

and my second table looks like

```
id                          date      timestamp T   hum temperature co      r   b     block f location
fd00::212:4b00:1957:d625    10-12-2019  08:24.6 0   6618    2648    1454    99  null    B2E L1  11
fd00::212:4b00:1957:d626    10-12-2019  13:23.2 0   6671    2630    1455    73  null    B2E L1  12
fd00::212:4b00:1957:d627    10-12-2019  18:25.5 0   6681    2627    1456    73  null    B2E L1  13
fd00::212:4b00:1957:d628    10-12-2019  23:23.3 0   6691    2626    1457    73  null    B2E L1  14
fd00::212:4b00:1957:d625    10-12-2019  28:24.1 0   6701    2626    1458    73  null    B2E L1  11
fd00::212:4b00:1957:d626    10-12-2019  33:24.1 0   6701    2626    1459    73  null    B2E L1  12
```

There are the two tables which i want to join on Id from first table and location from second table.  There is seperate mapping between Id and location. Like

```
Id    location
39    11
41    12
46    13
48    14
```

I have this mapping separately in an excel file. I could use a inner join if the columns from both the tables are same.How should I join these tables when there is an external mapping between the columns to join. Can some one help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: Load the Excel data into a table in the database.

Comment: I doubt MySQL can "look" at an Excel sheet. As Gordon says upload the third (Excel sheet) into MySQL. Once you do that the query is just a simple join.

Comment: There's https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-for-excel/en/mysql-for-excel-export.html but I find it's easier to just export from Excel to a CSV file, and then use LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE to get the CSV file into MySQL. If you have access to the MySQL datadir, you can also define the table using the CSV storage engine, and just plop the CSV file into the right location in the datadir to allow it to be read as a table.

Comment: But regardless, I agree with the other comments. You can't query Excel data from MySQL. You must load the mapping data into MySQL one way or another before you can solve this problem.